# SQL Server UDF SQLCLR Call Converts Characters Into Question Marks

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, encoding, sqlclr

I've found nothing on Google or SO that quites lines up with my issue.

In SQL Server, I have a scalar function (we'll call it `dbo.MySqlStringFunction`).
What this function does is call a utility written in C# that calls an ASP.Net view and returns the HTML as a SqlString.

The function definition in SQL Server is:

```
RETURNS [nvarchar](max) WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS EXTERNAL NAME [Utils.UserDefinedFunctions].[MySqlStringFunction]
```

The C# code simplified is:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("www.mydomain.com");

using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
   using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8)
   {
      return new SqlString(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
   }
}
```

When I put the C# code into a console app and run it, I get everything exactly as it should be.

When I access the URL directly in my browser, it displays exactly as it should be.

When I do `SELECT MySqlStringFunction()` however, characters such as ™, §, ¤ display as 2 or 3 question marks each.

It appears that it is somewhere between the `return new SqlString(..)` and the sql function returning the value that something is going wonky.  But I'm at a loss as to what it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue was the location of the `return`. The current code (shown in the Question), is returning in the middle of 3 `using` blocks, one of which is the UTF-8 stream being read. This probably confused things as SQLCLR is isolated memory from the main SQL Server memory, and usually you can't return via a stream. It is best to close the open stream first and let the `using` blocks call `Dispose()`. Hence:

1. Create a string above the first `using` (i.e. `string _TempReturn = String.Empty;`)
2. Inside the inner-most `using`, replace `return` with: `_TempReturn = streamReader.ReadToEnd();`
3. Below the last `using` closing bracket, add: `return new SqlString(_TempReturn);`

---

(*old answer, will remove in the near future*)

The problem is with the encoding difference between the web page and SQL Server. You are using `Encoding.UTF8` for the web page (which is quite likely correct given that UTF-8 is the most common encoding for the interwebs), but SQL Server (along with .NET and Windows in general) is UTF-16 Little Endian. This is why you are getting 2 or 3 `?`s for each character above Code Point 127: UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding that uses 1, 2, or 3 bytes per character, whereas UTF-16 is always 2-bytes (well, supplementary characters are 4 bytes, but that is due to being a pair of double-byte values).

You need to convert the encoding to UTF-16 Little Endian before, or as, you pass back the stream. And, UTF-16 Little Endian is the `Unicode` encoding in .NET, while `Big Endian Unicode` refers to "UTF-16 Big Endian". So you want to convert to the `Unicode` encoding.

OR, it could be the reverse: that the web page is NOT UTF-8, in which case you have declared it incorrectly in the `StreamReader`. If this is true, then you need to specify the correct encoding in the `StreamReader` constructor.

Comment: I used a `@Response.Charset` call in the view to verify that it is in fact utf-8.  When I put a breakpoint after calling the StreamReader, it shows the characters correctly.  And the text is stored correctly elsewhere in the database.  Also what do you mean by convert to the unicode encoding?  In the application as well, or just in this particular CLR assembly?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand what you're saying now.  I have `Encoding.Unicode` and `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` options for the StreamReader, I should use `Encoding.Unicode` because that's the .Net term for "Little Endian Unicode"

Comment: @Bardicer Why don't we try to eliminate `SqlString` from being the issue (it might be, if your server has a different default language setting than SQL Server). Just above the `return` can you put in a `throw new Exception(streamReader.ReadToEnd());` and then see which characters show up in the error message? Another test would be to instead return `SqlChars`, in which case you would `return new SqlChars(streamReader.ReadToEnd().ToCharArray());`

Comment: The `SqlString` and `SqlChars` have the same value.  It looks like everything is good up until the actual `return` call which sends the value to the SQL server function which then returns a value with corrupted characters.

Comment: @Bardicer Did you try throwing the exception? And you changed the return type to `SqlChars` in the signature for the `new SqlChars` test, right?

Comment: Yes. I am doing this in a console application (not being sent to the server yet), would that have any bearing on it?  Or does the error need to make it to sql server?

Comment: @Bardicer I am confused now. If you are using SQLCLR, then that is inherently not a Console App. What happens when you run `SELECT dbo.MySqlStringFunction();` ??

Comment: The code that is getting the characters is a  dll file which is created using C#.  This is registered in the SQLCLR and a sql server function calls it.  I have copied the operating code from the dll into a console application (actually a windows form application with a rich text box now) so i can see the output.  I'm doing my testing by running the windows form application.

Comment: When I run `SELECT dbo.MySqlStringFunction();` I get `??? ?? ?? ??  one of these should bust...`  However, when I'm running the code in an application where I can get a breakpoint, I get the following instead `<p>™\n‹\n©\n²\n» \none of these should bust...</p>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121780/discussion-between-srutzky-and-bardicer).